# .htaccess url rewrite getting the information after domain name

Tags: php

I am trying to use .htaccess url rewrite to transform the url:-

before: http://mydomain.com/en/Home

after: http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=en/Home

I know at .htaccess level, I shall prepare these:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=$X [L]
```

but I have no idea on how to put en/Home into $X and put it to the after version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried your codes and it works. But then I discover, when I press on menu with data "sc/Overview", the url grows liks this "/sc/sc/sc/sc/Overview", is it related to the .htaccess rewrite rule?

Comment: No that is not happening in my suggested solution above. You might have something else in .htaccess or in your framework. Post your complete .htaccess in your question then I can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish a match class

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```